# Trying to pull from a redis cache

Tags: javascript, postgresql, caching, redis

I am new-ish to programming and am developing an app that has an email verification step. I'm hoping to take information from input fields, save it in a cache, then pull it from the cache when users get to verfication page through a UUID in the email.

My steps so far are to:

1. Save the username and password they enter in the registration page to a redis cache called 'users' with username, password, and UUID keys and values
2. Set a cookie for the user containing the UUID so that when they return I can pull the username and password from cache based on a UUID-based query from the cookie. (This is where I am having trouble, as I can't figure out how to search the redis cache by a field value).
3. Once the username and password can be accessed via the cache with the UUID, I will be inserting them into a Postgres DB.

Any thoughts? Or links to good redis documentation?

Another thought is, should I be using a hash rather than a set?
Cachers to the rescue please!

Comment: Does this have to work at very large scale? If not, I'd just have a pending subscriptions table in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You don't search a redis server, you access a key. This is a critical piece of understanding. Also, as you aren't using it as a cache it can be useful to not refer to it as one.

The trick to designing your redis data structure is to determine how you will use it when you pull data from it and store it that way, not store then figure it out.

Here is how, if I had to, I'd structure what you are doing in redis:
For a given UUID. Create a Redis hash with the UUID as the name of the hash. The hash will have the key/value pairs (or members) of username, password (please at least store it encrypted), and any other key/value pairs you use in the session.

This allows you to access precisely the data you are after, and you can look it up with the UUID. Basically the UUID identifies a particular collection of data.

Comment: Thank you! I did indeed end up using a Redis hash with the UUID as the name and it worked perfectly for what I needed.